# How do I move a client/wallet to a different machine?

Tags: client, wallet

I have a client/wallet on a work machine of which I cannot control the proxy and allow the client to synchronise properly. Before I knew this however, I sent coins to the wallet. How do migrate this wallet to my home machine, so I can receive the transaction?

I am using [Bitcoin-Qt](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Bitcoin-Qt).

Answer (score 5):

Copy the wallet.dat onto another machine, put it in [the appropriate folder](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Data_directory) and either sync your Bitcoin from the Genesis Block with the network, or run it with `-rescan` [option](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Running_Bitcoin).

Comment: -rescan is probably unnecessary. According to sipa, from a certain version (much earlier than what the OP is using) the wallet.dat file keeps track of which is the latest block it knows, and automatically rescans from that point onward.

Comment: Since 0.3.21, in fact (april 2011).